# How would I make a smooth crease in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I was thinking some sort of mesh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not everything is a filter in Illustrator.

Starting with four lines:

- Blue = *Waves*
- Red = *Frame*
- Green = *Spine*

[image: Scheme]

- Selecting the *Waves* > **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Make**
- **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Blend options** > **Specified Steps** = 20
- Selecting the Blend and the *Spine* > **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Replace Spine**
- **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Expand**
- **Menu Object** > **Ungroup**
- Selecting the new *Waves* and the *Frame*, get the **Shape Builder Tool**

[image: Shape Builder Tool]

and click where the shapes must be filled

- Fill them and delete the unused paths.

[image: flag]

End:

[image: End Flag]

Comment: If your going to be elborate add a line peak to peak on the lower creases

Answer (score 6):

If you look carefully on the image youll notice that the upper and lower line is the same. Then just shift them in relation

[image]

start with x copies, then shift the lines

[image]

and finally join and fill.

[image]

Fix any small details and cut to length